# Replace any number of chars with another char

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript's replace function how do I replace multiple chars with the same char?

```
Input = "blah...blah..blah....blah"
Output = "blah.blah.blah.blah"
```

Comment: Does it need to be any character, or a specific one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
input = input.replace(/\.+/g, ".");
```

Comment: actually you need to do `replace(/\.+/g, ".")` if you want to replace all matches. Otherwise you get `"blah.blah..blah....blah"`.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but `/\.\.+/g` might give slightly better performance because it will not spend time replacing a single `.` with itself. This could just be paranoid when working with strings, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to match *any* repeated characters and not just a period, you can use:

```
input = input.replace(/(.)\1+/g, "$1");
```

So `blaaaah...blahhh..blah....bbblah` becomes `blah.blah.blah.blah`

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript regular expression replacement comes to mind, searching for (.+) and replacing with .

Something like

```
s.replace(/(\.+)/mg,".");
```

Untested, but should be close enough to give you a push in the right direction. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Between the brackets you set your char, e.g. with ".":

```
var s = "blah ... blah ...";
s.replace(/[.]+/gi, '.')
alert(s);
```

So: replace any number of X with one of Y

```
s.replace(/[X]+/gi, 'Y');
```